# How to avoid the 2nd alignment is affected by the 1st alignment?

Tags: regex, vim, alignment, tabular

My text example:

```
this is my text,this is,this is my text
this, this is my,this is my,this is text
```

I use [Tabular](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plug-in to align text.

When I want to align at the 1st and 2nd occurrence of a single space `'\s'` I use these lines:

```
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs\s\)\{1}/l0
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs\s\)\{2}/l0
```

But I noted that the 1st alignment add spaces in order to align, 
but the 2nd alignment is influenced by these extra spaces added and does not the right job.

How can I avoid this?
(I hope I made myself clear)

**Edit:**

This is what I expected:

```
this  is   my text,this is,this is my aatext
this, this is my,this is my,this is rtext
```

This is the outcome:

```
this       is my text,this is,this is my aatext
this, this is my,this is my,this is rtext
```

**Edit2:**

This is my example with >= 2 spaces:

```
this  is my  text, this is,this  is my aatext
this,  this    is my, this is my,  this is rtext
```

Adapting the code proposed by Nikita Kouevda in his answer below:

```
Tabularize /\(^\(\(\S*\s\{2,}\)\{0}\|\(\S*\s\{2,}\)\{2}\)\)\@<=\S*\zs\s/l0
```

I expected:

```
this  is my  text, this is,this  is my aatext
this, this    is my, this is my, this is rtext
```

Outcome:

```
this  is my  text, this is,this  is my aatext
this, this                                     is my, this is my,  this is rtext
```

Comment: Would you mind providing some samples showing what it's doing now as compared to the desired output?

Comment: @Denomales Sure, done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Tabular and there might be an option to do this, but I would simply change the second `\s` to `\s\+` in order to match any amount of whitespace:

```
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs\s\+\)\{2}/l0
```

**Edit:** Here's a more proper solution, combining the steps into one:

```
Tabularize /\(^\(\S*\s\)\{,1}\)\@<=\S*\zs\s/l0
```

The first part is a lookbehind that matches up to the 0th or 1st space, any non-whitespace characters are then skipped, and the next space is matched (the 1st and 2nd, respectively). This can be generalized to any range; e.g. to align by the 2nd through 5th spaces, use `\{1,4}`.

**Edit:** If you need to align by a set of spaces that do not constitute a range in that sense, I would utilize logical ORs in the lookbehind. Unfortunately, this becomes much more clumsy and repetitive. For example, to align by the 1st and 3rd spaces:

```
Tabularize /\(^\(\(\S*\s\)\{0}\|\(\S*\s\)\{2}\)\)\@<=\S*\zs\s/l0
```

In order to align each column differently, specify multiple `[lcr]#` formats. Note that every separating and separated column is counted; e.g. an alignment by 2 spaces results in 5 columns that will be formatted. In order to align by the 1st and 3rd spaces, and to right justify the middle column of text:

```
Tabularize /\(^\(\(\S*\s\)\{0}\|\(\S*\s\)\{2}\)\)\@<=\S*\zs\s/l0l0r0l0l0
```

Since the formats cycle if you specify fewer than the number of columns, `l0l0r0` would also suffice here, but it's probably a good idea to be explicit.

Comment: No that's not what I want. I want to align only the single spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; the output of what I suggest matches your expected output.

Comment: Yes in my simple example the output is as I wanted with your answer but it is not quit a solution to my question. Your code will align also fields with more then 1 space. How can I align only the field with a fix nr. of spaces? But... if there is no better solution I'll use yours. :)

Comment: The question is: How can I combine both commands above, as if the 1st commands works on the first space, and the 2nd command works on the second space?

Comment: Great found! Yes it does what I need. I'm now trying to format different for every column. Is this not possible? All columns must be formatted the same? (l0 or r1 or..)

Comment: Btw.. just to better learn the code: what if the columns are not in sequence, like the 1st space and the 3 spaces on a line? ;)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Why doesn't it work with fields of 2 and more spaces? p.e. `Tabularize /\(^\(\(\S*\s\{2,}\)\{0}\|\(\S*\s\{2,}\)\{2}\)\)\@<=\S*\zs\s\{2,}/l0` Maybe I didn't understand your code completely :)

Comment: If you're trying that with the same example, then because it only contains single spaces. If you `:%s/\s/\0\0/g` and then try again, it will work.

Comment: Yes, I know but before to try the double space example I added a few space between the text (4 field from 1 space to 2 spaces in every line) but it didn't work :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then; it works for me. You might want `\zs\s/l0` instead of `\zs\s\{2,}/l0` though.

Comment: I adapted my question above in order to show the example. I would like to know what did I wrong. If you don't know, no matter. Your answer is already very helpful. :-) Thanks again!